# Form_validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I need to validate field username.I want to show required error when the field is empty otherwise it should call the callback_exist. But it is showing the callback_exist's error message every time.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('first');
    $config=array
    (
        [   
            'field'=>'username',
            'rules' =>'required|min_length[5]|callback_exist',
            'label'=>'username',
            'errors'=>array(
                'required'=>'its required',
                'min_length'=>'please enter correct',
            )
        ],

    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {

        $this->load->view('form_view');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}


public function exist()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('exist','dont exists');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your callback function is not implemented well according to [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods). You should have an argument in `exist($username)` method, then sort logic with if than else block to return wether true or false. With explicitly `return false;` you are telling form_validation library not to pass.

Comment: Actually I read the documentation but couldn't get it.Would you like to help me ?

Comment: Sure. Go to link I provided in comment above, read the section again and spot the difference between your `exists()` method and one written there called `username_check($str)`. Pay attention on argument `$str` one you didn't follow.